# Same x axis ranges for subplots in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to make subplots in Plotly. I have two rows which plot time series data from two different data frames. I want the x axis in the two subplots to be in the sane range. How can I do this?

This is the code that I have for my plotly subplots:

```
trace_df1 = go.Scatter(
   y=df1[“y”],
   x=df1[“x”]
)

trace_df2 = go.Scatter(
    y=df2[“y”],
    x=df2[“x”]
)


fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
fig.append_trace(trace_df1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace_df2, 2, 1)
```

Comment: @Just a basic question on the data structure? Do the time series have the same timeindex? I'm guessing "no" since they're not organized in the same dataframe...

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: Really good answer, @vestland . Thanks. I appreciate the effort that you took for this detailed answer. The answer works. =)

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm basing this suggestion on the assumption that you've got two different time-series for `two different or over-lapping time indexes`. Or else this wouldn't be much of a challenge. I'm going to assume that the time series are of the `same length` though.

**Plot for starting point:**

[image]

**Code for starting point:**

```
# imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data 1
np.random.seed(123)
frame_rows = 40
frame_columns = ['V_1']
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-10,10,size=(frame_rows, len(frame_columns))),
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=frame_rows),
                    columns=frame_columns)
df_1=df_1.cumsum()+100
df_1.iloc[0]=100
df_1

# data 2
frame_rows = 40
frame_columns = ['V_1']
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-10,11,size=(frame_rows, len(frame_columns))),
                  index=pd.date_range('2/2/2020', periods=frame_rows),
                    columns=frame_columns)
df_2=df_2.cumsum()+100
df_2.iloc[0]=100

# plotly
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_1.index, y=df_1['V_1']))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_2.index, y=df_2['V_1']))
fig.show()
```

**Plot for suggested solution:**

Note that the upper x-axis is hidden using `fig['layout']['xaxis']['tickfont']['color']='rgba(0,0,0,0)'`

[image]

**Code for suggested solution:**

```
df_1b = df_1.reset_index()
df_1b

df_2b = df_1.reset_index()
df_2b

# source data, integer as index
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_1b.index, y=df_1['V_1']), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_2b['index'], y=df_2['V_1']), row=2, col=1)
fig['layout']['xaxis']['tickfont']['color']='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
fig.show()
```

Comment: Really good answer, @vestland . Thanks. I appreciate the effort that you took for this detailed answer. The answer works. =)